# fminsearch on a function internally using matrices

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I'm having trouble minimizing a rather complicated function:

```
% Current densities - psi is a 4x1 fourvector
j0 = @(psi) psi' * psi;

% Solutions
chi1 = @(n_,r_,kt_,theta_) ...
       1/sqrt(2) * ...
           [ exp(1i*n_*theta_) .* besselj(n_,kt_*r_); ...
             exp(1i*(n_+1)*theta_) .* besselj(n_+1,kt_*r_) ];
chi2 = @(n_,r_,kt_,theta_) ...
       1/sqrt(2) * ...
           [  exp(1i*n_*theta_) .* besselj(n_,kt_*r_); ...
             -exp(1i*(n_+1)*theta_) .* besselj(n_+1,kt_*r_) ];

uplus = @(n_,E_,m_,r_,kz_,kt_,theta_) ...
        sqrt((E_+m_)/(4*m_)) * ...
            [ chi1(n_,r_,kt_,theta_); ...
              (kz_-1i*kt_)/(E_+m_) * chi2(n_,r_,kt_,theta_) ];
```

Here: n,E,m,kz,theta are all constants for any purpose. I need to fit `j0` to a step function (1 for r=1...10), and the model function being the four-vector psi, consisting of summing uplus over `kt`=zeros of `besselj(n,kt/10*r)`, so that besselj(0,kt*10) is zero. The problem is that `fminsearch` doesn't like my complicated setup:

```
uplus_reduced  = @(r_,kt_) uplus(0,E,m,r_,kz,kt_,0);
error_function = @(r_,coeffs_) error_j0_stepfunction(r_,coeffs_,...
                               uplus_reduced);
coeffs(1,:) = fminsearch( @(r) error_function(r',coeffs(:,1)), r);
```

where `error_j0_stepfunction` is this:

```
function error = error_j0_stepfunction(r,coeffs,basisspinor)
% Zeros of BesselJ
Nzeros = 100;
lambda = [ besselzero(0,Nzeros,1)';
           besselzero(1,Nzeros,1)';
           besselzero(2,Nzeros,1)' ];

% calculate psi= sum over zeros
psi = zeros(4,length(r));
for k=1:length(coeffs)
    size_psi = size(psi(:,:) )
    size_coeffs = size(coeffs(k))
    size_basisspinor = size( basisspinor(r(:)', lambda(1,k)/10))
    psi(:,:) = psi(:,:) + coeffs(k) * ...
        basisspinor(r(:), lambda(1,k)/10);
end;
% calculate density (j0)
density = zeros(1,length(r));
for k=1:length(r)
    density(k) = j0(psi(:,k));
end;
% calculate square error
error = sum((1-density(:)).^2);
end
```

I hope I have been clear enough, and at the same time concise so this can be answered. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: The error I get is this (with output making it nonsensical to me):

```
size_psi = 4        1000
size_coeffs = 1     1
size_basisspinor = 4        1000
Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in error_j0_stepfunction (line 15)
    psi(:,:) = psi(:,:) + coeffs(k) * ...
Error in @(r_,coeffs_)error_j0_stepfunction(r_,coeffs_,uplus_reduced)
Error in @(r)error_function(r',coeffs(:,1))
Error in fminsearch (line 191)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
Error in dirac_stepfunction (line 17)
coeffs(1,:) = fminsearch( @(r) error_function(r',coeffs(:,1)), r);
Error in dirac (line 7)
dirac_stepfunction;
```

It should make enough sense to anyone reading the error and code above. coeffs is a 20x3 matrix, r is a 1x1000 (or 1000x1)

Comment: What is the problem that you encounter when using `fminsearch`?

Comment: silvado: see my edit. I get a nonsensical error about a dimension mismatch, but as far as I can tell, all matrices match (hence the `size` statements in my code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `basisspinor` in the `size`-statement has `r(:)'` as first argument, while the second call to `basisspinor` has just `r(:)`. I guess the first version was also intended for the second call.

Comment: Wow, the typo has got me again. Thanks for your time!